# listing text-based data from column C in multiple sheets into a single column in a master sheet in excel

Tags: excel

I have a workbook filled with text-based data on several different sheets. All the sheets use the same headings, but have different text in the columns. I would like to be able to list the information contained in the column C from all of the sheets in a single column in a new sheet.

Is there a way to get all of that data into a single column without having to copy and past from nearly 100 different sheets?

Comment: Are you opposed to using a little VBA?  It's pretty simple in that.

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA, here is a solution that works.  You just need to insert a module into your workbook and run this.  F11 > Insert > Module.   Copy and paste this code, and hit play.

This will create a new worksheet with whatever name you define under newSheet. Then take the contents of EVERY worksheet Row C (after header), no matter how many you have or what their name is, and add them to the new one.  I could see a problem if you exceed 1,000,000 rows..  Other than that, if there are any sheets you DON'T want to perform this on, we would add them as exceptions specifically by name in the If statement.

**TESTED:**

```
Private Sub CopyAllSheetsCol()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim newSheet As String
Dim lastRow As Long     'Last Row on source Sheet
Dim tRow As Long        'target row  

newSheet = "Compiled"   'name can be changed here

Sheets.Add.Name = newSheet
tRow = 2                'Set the target Row to 2, Set the Header Row manually

    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> newSheet Then     'Making sure we are only working with pre-existing sheets

            lastRow = Sheets(WS.Name).Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row    'get last row of Column C on each Worksheet

            For r = 2 To lastRow                                'Loop through all rows skipping header
            Sheets(newSheet).Cells(tRow, "C") = Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(r, "C")    'Copy to newSheet
            tRow = tRow + 1                                     'Increment target row by 1
            Next r

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]
[image: Sheet3]
[image: Result]

edit:  touched up explanation